# Wait for function to execute first before moving to next line of code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit in my app and facing problem showing data in table view. In `viewDidLoad()` I am fetching data from CloudKit database.

Then in table view functions I do `CKRecord` object count for number of rows.

But count returns 0 to table view and after few seconds returns number of row. Because of this table view does not show the results.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadNewData()
}

func loadNewData() {
    self.loadData = [CKRecord]()
    let publicData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let qry = CKQuery(recordType: "Transactions", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    qry.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Transaction_ID", ascending: true)]
    publicData.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
        if let rcds = results {
            self.loadData = rcds
        }
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return loadData.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! ViewAllTransactionsTVCell

    let pn = loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Party_Name") as! String
    let amt = loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Amount") as! String
    let nrt = loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Narattions") as! String 
    let dt = loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Trans_Date") as! String


    cell.partyNameLabel.text = pn
    cell.dateLabel.text = dt
    cell.narationLabel.text = nrt
    cell.amountLabel.text = amt

    return cell
}
```

Comment: In answer to your question, don't "wait". Just call `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the `publicData.perform` completion handler. If you try to wait, you can introduce all sorts of subtle problems. By the way, if you're wondering about the down vote, it's undoubtedly because this question has been asked and answered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow. Just search for "[ios] wait for function" or, more narrowly, "[ios] cloudkit wait".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't wait, but instead trigger the reloading of the data when the `perform` completion handler is called:

```
publicData.perform(qry, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) in
    if let rcds = results {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.loadData = rcds
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    if error != nil {
        self.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
    }
}
```

Note, I'm dispatching the reload process to the main queue, because you're not guaranteed to have this run on the main thread. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/1449127-perform) says:

> Your block must be capable of running on any thread of the app ...

And because UI updates must happen on the main thread (and because you want to synchronize your access to `loadData`), just dispatch this to the main queue, like above.

Comment: hi. thanks for reply. finally it calls the tableview functions. but now i am getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. tried every thing but no luck

Comment: Well, you'd have to identify what line is causing that error, wouldn't you. A likely candidate, though, was `loadData`. How did you define that? If it was an optional, your `numberOfRowsInSection` should return `loadData?.count ?? 0` (i.e. safely unwrap it if it can, return zero if not). If that's not where you're getting the "found `nil` while unwrapping an Optional", then tell us which line is generating that error.

Comment: The error is from tableView(...cell for row ) fn line 2nd where i have used "let pn = loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Party_Name") as! String" and maybe other lines will cause that to because it stops there with error

Comment: @Aakash So, the problem is after you successfully return data from CloudKit? OK, then what did `loadData` actually contain? Perhaps your key names are not right. You need to do some diagnostics to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: 'loadData' returns correct values i think because it returns actual number of rows. for keys- Party_Name is of String, Trans_Date is of String, Amount is of Double, Narattions is of String and i don't know what is causing error.

Comment: You say `Amount` is `Double`. But your code is trying to cast it to a `String`. Which is it? Is that the line where it's crashing? Also, double check the keys (the capitalization matters, for example). I'd suggest printing `loadData[indexPath.row]` and double check everything. It's going to be something simple like this.

Comment: ok. will do that. second thing i am getting same error in another viewcontroller. let me check and revert to you

Comment: Basically, you should be wary of using `!` or `as!` unless you know with 100% certainty, that the cast will succeed. Otherwise use `if let`, `guard let`, `as?` or nil coalescing operator to safely unwrap and safely cast.

Comment: print(loadData.count)
print(loadData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "Party_Name")!)   i use this and get same error.

Comment: @Aakash If `Party_Name` wasn't found, the use of `!` will crash. Just `print(loadData[indexPath.row])`.

Comment: <CKRecord: 0x159d3b4b0; recordID=97C4AC61-F016-4DA8-8D42-C68D891EE729:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=j4va5emv, values={
    Amount = 100000;
    Narattions = Narrations;
    Party = Gemee;
    "Trans_Date" = "08/07/2017 18:12";
    "Transaction_ID" = 4;
}, recordType=Transactions>    this is the result of print(loadData[indexPart.row])

Comment: Alas, there's nothing called `Party_Name`. It's just `Party`.

Comment: Oh! How can i did this and make a problem for u too. Sorry. Will correct this and revert to you. thanks.